# Adding a history feature to my simple shell

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80 /* 80 chars per line, per command, should be enough. */

/**
 * setup() reads in the next command line, separating it into distinct tokens
 * using whitespace as delimiters. It also sets the args parameter as a 
 * null-terminated string.
 */

void setup(char inputBuffer[], char *args[],int *background)
{
    int length, /* Number  of characters in the command line */
        i,      /* Loop index for inputBuffer array */
        start,  /* Index where beginning of next command parameter is */
        ct;     /* Index of where to place the next parameter into args[] */

    ct = 0;

    /* Read what the user enters on the command line */
    length = read(STDIN_FILENO, inputBuffer, MAX_LINE);  

    start = -1;
    if (length == 0)
        exit(0);            /* ^d was entered, end of user command stream */
    if (length < 0){
        perror("error reading command");
    exit(-1);           /* terminate with error code of -1 */
    }

    /* Examine every character in the inputBuffer */
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
        switch (inputBuffer[i]){
        case ' ':
        case '\t' :               /* argument separators */
            if(start != -1){
                args[ct] = &inputBuffer[start];    /* set up pointer */
                ct++;
            }
            inputBuffer[i] = '\0'; /* add a null char; make a C string */
            start = -1;
            break;

        case '\n':                 /* should be the final char examined */
            if (start != -1){
                args[ct] = &inputBuffer[start];     
                ct++;
            }
            inputBuffer[i] = '\0';
            args[ct] = NULL; /* no more arguments to this command */
            break;

        case '&':
            *background = 1;
            inputBuffer[i] = '\0';
            break;

        default :             /* some other character */
            if (start == -1)
                start = i;
    } 
    }    
    args[ct] = NULL; /* just in case the input line was > 80 */
} 

int main(void)
{
    char inputBuffer[MAX_LINE]; /* Buffer to hold the command entered */
    int background;             /* Equals 1 if a command is followed by '&' */
    char *args[MAX_LINE/2+1];/* Command line (of 80) has max of 40 arguments */


    while (1){            /* program terminates normally inside setup */
    background = 0;
    printf("CSE2431Sh->");
        fflush(0);
        setup(inputBuffer, args, &background);       /* get next command */

        int child_pid;
        int status;

        child_pid = fork();

        if(child_pid == 0)
        {
                execvp(args[0],args);
                /* If execvp returns, it must have failed. */

                printf("Execvp Failed\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
                if(background == 0)
                {
                        int parent_pid;
                        while ((parent_pid = wait(&status)) != -1 && parent_pid != child_pid)
                                ;
                }
                else
                {
                        setup(inputBuffer, args, &background);
                }
        }
   }
}
```

I'm trying to add a history feature to the shell and I'm not sure how to go about it. The shell should store the command and number the. It should also be able to recover the last 8 commands to run again. For example if 35 commands have been entered by the user 28-35 should be able to be recovered. The user should be able to see the last 8 commands by typing history and run a previous command by typing x num, where num is the number of the command, or xr to run the most recent.

Comment: What is your specific question about this topic? What have you tried? What worked? What didn't work? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a `linked list` where you additionally store the length, first and last item of the list? The items being the commands from your `inputBuffer`.

Comment: It's been a long time since I logged into SO but this is what I did

Answer (score 0):

For your history command store all each typed in command in a linked list that you limit at 8 entries. Once you have 9 linked commands you delete the oldest one.

Amout the command count you can have a global variable or just an incremented int that you display in your prompt.

Hope this can help you!