# Adding history feature to shell

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80 /* 80 chars per line, per command, should be enough. */

/**
 * setup() reads in the next command line, separating it into distinct tokens
 * using whitespace as delimiters. It also sets the args parameter as a 
 * null-terminated string.
 */

typedef struct list
{
   int num;
   int *ptr;
   struct history * next;
}history;

void setup(char inputBuffer[], char *args[],int *background)
{
    int length, /* Number  of characters in the command line */
        i,      /* Loop index for inputBuffer array */
        start,  /* Index where beginning of next command parameter is */
        ct;     /* Index of where to place the next parameter into args[] */

    ct = 0;

    /* Read what the user enters on the command line */
    length = read(STDIN_FILENO, inputBuffer, MAX_LINE);  

    start = -1;
    if (length == 0)
        exit(0);            /* ^d was entered, end of user command stream */
    if (length < 0){
        perror("error reading command");
    exit(-1);           /* terminate with error code of -1 */
    }

    /* Examine every character in the inputBuffer */
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
        switch (inputBuffer[i]){
        case ' ':
        case '\t' :               /* argument separators */
            if(start != -1){
                args[ct] = &inputBuffer[start];    /* set up pointer */
                ct++;
            }
            inputBuffer[i] = '\0'; /* add a null char; make a C string */
            start = -1;
            break;

        case '\n':                 /* should be the final char examined */
            if (start != -1){
                args[ct] = &inputBuffer[start];     
                ct++;
            }
            inputBuffer[i] = '\0';
            args[ct] = NULL; /* no more arguments to this command */
            break;

        case '&':
            *background = 1;
            inputBuffer[i] = '\0';
            break;

        default :             /* some other character */
            if (start == -1)
                start = i;
    } 
    }    
    args[ct] = NULL; /* just in case the input line was > 80 */
} 

int main(void)
{
    char inputBuffer[MAX_LINE]; /* Buffer to hold the command entered */
    int background;             /* Equals 1 if a command is followed by '&' */
    char *args[MAX_LINE/2+1];/* Command line (of 80) has max of 40 arguments */


    while (1){            /* program terminates normally inside setup */
    background = 0;
    printf("CSE2431Sh->");
        fflush(0);
        setup(inputBuffer, args, &background);       /* get next command */

    /* the steps are:
     (1) fork a child process using fork()
     (2) the child process will invoke execvp()
     (3) if background == 0, the parent will wait, 
        otherwise returns to the setup() function. */

        int child_pid;
        int status;
        int ph;
        history *history = NULL;

        child_pid = fork();

        if(child_pid == 0)
        {
                ph++;
                history->num = ph;
                history->ptr = args;
                execvp(args[0],args);
                /* If execvp returns, it must have failed. */

                printf("Execvp Failed\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
                if(background == 0)
                {
                        int parent_pid;
                        while ((parent_pid = wait(&status)) != -1 && parent_$
                                ;
                }
                else
                {
                        setup(inputBuffer, args, &background);
                }
        }
   }
}
```

I'm trying to add a history feature to a shell. The shell should store the command and number the. It should also be able to recover the last 8 commands to run again. For example if 35 commands have been entered by the user 28-35 should be able to be recovered. The user should be able to see the last 8 commands by typing history and run a previous command by typing x num, where num is the number of the command, or xr to run the most recent. My plan was to use a linked list but I'm having trouble with it and don't have but a few hours to complete it.

Comment: What problems do you have with this assignment?  The more specific you can be in your question, the better the chances someone will be able to help you.

Comment: "[You] don't have but a few hours to complete it"?  The answer to specific programming problem isn't time dependent.  If a linked list is the right answer to this, it will be the right answer to this now, and in six months from now, too.

Comment: If the number of commands to be saved in the history has a fixed number, you can use an array. When the index reaches the end of the array wrap it around to the beginning. No lists or pointers needed. Google circular buffer.

Comment: Voting to close, SO is not a homework producing service, however late you left it to get your assignment done.

Answer (score 0):

As we recommended in your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244314/adding-a-history-feature-to-my-simple-shell/19244444#19244444):

> How about a `linked list` where you additionally store the length, first
>   and last item of the list? The items being the commands from your
>   inputBuffer.

Comment: I tried the linked list if you look at the code it's been added. I'm having trouble completing it

Comment: This is not a full implementation of `linked lists`, [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html) is a link to a tutorial that will help you.